# Query that returns only values when all its products are in a specific condition

Tags: mysql

I have a select that returns a table like in the following example.

```
list    product location    created
790525  535107  A13.01  2014-08-05 10:47:45
790525  535107  A33.04  2014-08-05 10:47:45
798899  502279  A21.06  2014-06-16 14:27:11
798899  502284  A19.03  2014-06-16 14:00:40
798899  502284  C.06.12 2014-06-16 14:00:40
804005  624390  C.19.00 2014-10-07 16:10:44
804005  624390  A.17.07 2014-10-07 16:47:08
804005  625333  C.01.01 2014-10-05 14:00:01
804738  537045  C.41.06 2014-08-04 18:20:08
```

This query is already grouped by list and product and ordered by the created date. I can't seem to find a way to create a query that returns all the list numbers where for all products there is a location started with "A" as it's oldest locations.

In the above example it would return 790525 (oldest location for its only product is A13.01), 798899 (oldest location for both its products starts with A) and nothing else. Because the remaining lists don't have an oldest location started with A.

Can anyone here wrap their heads around this? I need this in a single query but at this point any solution would be welcome.

Comment: Related: [`greatest-n-per-group`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977782/mysql-subquery-find-only-first-record-in-a-left-join) (or `least-n-per-group`, the problem is the same).

Comment: Please note that it helps people write the query if you give the name of your table.  At least the answers can be consistent that way.

Comment: Does it help to rephrase the question as: select all data for lists where the count of the products where the location in the oldest row starts with A is the same as the count of the products in that list?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem is that this table isn't one table. It's the result of a select that joins many tables together so it does really have a name. Regarding your second comment. That does seem like a good description of the problem. I have thought of that but, honestly, didn't know how I'd do that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @RicardoMota did you ever solve this one?

Comment: I did solve this issue with the help of a colleague. Since my actual table is the result of many joins I can't just paste the solution here without simplifying it to match the example given. I didn't have the time yet but I will be posting a solution during the weekend. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments pointed out, you are looking for the greatest N items per group. In this case, You want to get the earliest item in each group, which you can do like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable m
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable mt
  WHERE mt.list = m.list AND mt.created <= m.created) <= 1;
```

Then, all you will have to do is filter for the rows where the location starts with A. You can do that using a wildcard:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable m
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable mt
  WHERE mt.list = m.list AND mt.created <= m.created) <= 1
AND m.location LIKE 'A%';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0d04/2) and more [information](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) on getting rows within groups.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of query is tough using SQL without the OLAP functions — I suspect it might be easier with OLAP functions, but I'm not expert enough in them to be sure.  MySQL 5.7 does not seem to support the `WITH` clause which allows you to name sub-queries, which makes this more complex.

I tackle such queries through what I call TDQD — Test Driven Query Design.  I build the query in stages, and each stage can be tested in isolation.  Corrections can be made if necessary.

I'm working from the reformulated query posited in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112168/query-that-returns-only-values-when-all-its-products-are-in-a-specific-condition#comment42729595_27112168):

> [R]ephrase the question as: select all data for lists where the count of the products where the location in the oldest row starts with A is the same as the count of the products in that list.

The Q in the headings of the sections is 'query', not 'question'.

#### Q1 — Generate the table shown in the question

The table shown in the question is itself the result of a complex query.  But we've got to write something here.  So, we'll assume that the query that generates that result is:

```
SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist
```

This expression will appear (frequently) in the subsequent queries.  You should consider whether it makes sense to create a view that generates the result, or whether to create a temporary table that contains the result, or whether just to write it out in full each time it appears.

#### Q2 — Count of items in each list

```
SELECT list, COUNT(DISTINCT product) AS num_products
  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
 GROUP BY list
```

#### Q3 — Oldest entry for each product in a list

```
SELECT list, product, MIN(created) AS oldest
  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
 GROUP BY list, product
```

#### Q4 — First letter of location of oldest entry for each product in a list

This combines the result from Q3 with the data from Q1:

```
SELECT p.list, p.product, SUBSTR(p.location, 1, 1) AS loc_code
  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
  JOIN (SELECT list, product, MIN(created) AS oldest
          FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
         GROUP BY list, product) AS o
    ON p.list = o.list AND p.product = o.product AND p.created = o.oldest
```

#### Q5 — Count of products per list where oldest entry is in location starting with A

This summarizes a mildly modified version of Q4:

```
SELECT list, COUNT(*) AS num_products
  FROM (SELECT p.list, p.product
          FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
          JOIN (SELECT list, product, MIN(created) AS oldest
                  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created
                          FROM prodlist) AS p
                 GROUP BY list, product) AS o
            ON p.list = o.list AND p.product = o.product AND
               p.created = o.oldest
         WHERE SUBSTR(p.location, 1, 1) = 'A') AS n
 GROUP BY list
```

#### Q6 — Lists where the number of items is the same in Q2 and Q5

Q2 and Q5 give us the two numbers we need to compare for each list.  We're interested only in the lists where the numbers are the same, so we can join the two subqueries:

```
SELECT c1.list
  FROM (SELECT list, COUNT(DISTINCT product) AS num_products
          FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
         GROUP BY list
       ) AS c1
  JOIN (SELECT list, COUNT(*) AS num_products
          FROM (SELECT p.list, p.product
                  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created
                          FROM prodlist) AS p
                  JOIN (SELECT list, product, MIN(created) AS oldest
                          FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created
                                  FROM prodlist) AS p
                         GROUP BY list, product) AS o
                    ON p.list = o.list AND p.product = o.product AND
                       p.created = o.oldest
                 WHERE SUBSTR(p.location, 1, 1) = 'A') AS n
         GROUP BY list
       ) AS c2
    ON c1.list = c2.list AND c1.num_products = c2.num_products
```

#### Q7 — Full information for each item from the lists in Q6

This simply joins the result of Q6 with the original query to get the correct data.  It is not the sort of query that springs to mind when you are presented with the problem, but if you've followed the steps, it all makes sense.  And if you've tested each step, then you know what you need to debug at each step — the new material in this step, rather than the old material from previous steps.

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created FROM prodlist) AS p
  JOIN (SELECT c1.list
          FROM (SELECT list, COUNT(DISTINCT product) AS num_products
                  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created
                          FROM prodlist) AS p
                 GROUP BY list
               ) AS c1
          JOIN (SELECT list, COUNT(*) AS num_products
                  FROM (SELECT p.list, p.product
                          FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created
                                  FROM prodlist) AS p
                          JOIN (SELECT list, product, MIN(created) AS oldest
                                  FROM (SELECT list, product, location, created
                                          FROM prodlist) AS p
                                 GROUP BY list, product) AS o
                            ON p.list = o.list AND p.product = o.product AND
                               p.created = o.oldest
                         WHERE SUBSTR(p.location, 1, 1) = 'A') AS n
                 GROUP BY list
               ) AS c2
            ON c1.list = c2.list AND c1.num_products = c2.num_products
       ) AS q
    ON p.list = q.list
 ORDER BY p.list, p.product, p.created
```

Note that the Q1 expression appears 4 times in Q7.

Designing and developing a query can be tough going.  Building and testing it in stages generally makes the process easier, just like breaking down a program into function makes it easier to write a program.

---

<sup>***Warning:*** *Untested code*</sup>